# Google Cloud Endpoint Client Library Generation Not Working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to generate my first Google Cloud Endpoint and am having trouble generating the client libraries.

First I try doing it with the GPE.  It generates an endpoints-libs folder in the Eclipse project with a bunch of files.  The readme.html says, "The generated service-specific library can be found in the top level directory of the zip file: google-api-services-mayapp-v1-rev20140417180959-1.16.0-rc.jar".  There is no such file generated.

Second, I try to generate with the appengine-sdk.  It creates myapp-v1-java.zip, which contains the same files and structure that GPE generates, but I don't see any JAR in there that would contain my endpoints.

I'm using Eclipse Juno Release 2 and GPE 3.5.1.  Just did a Check Updates and I appear to be up to date.

NOTE: I am not using Maven and prefer to continue not using it if possible.

How does one generate the client libraries?

Comment: More detail on this and using a Google Cloud Endpoint from a Java client here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177772/generating-google-cloud-endpoints-for-java-client

Comment: I saw [your post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/4CEZnaOq4DY) on the App Engine groups about Maven, and I don't really understand why you don't use it (or any other build tool based on Maven repositories, such as Gradle). Life is much simpler with those tools o0

Comment: I have a very simple philosophy.  I only use a library, framework, tool etc if it adds value.  Many things make it easy to do something easy (Microsoft was good with this in terms of its IDEs early on).  But as a professional I'm working on complex projects and  need tools that make it easier to do difficult things.  Hibernate is the perfect example of another tool I see as having marginal value. Why would I want to learn Hibernate's query language as opposed to SQL?  I would have difficulty doing many of the queries I need to do in Hibernate.  These are beyond simple CRUD.

Comment: Ok, if you don't see the problem Maven solves for you, I can do nothing. I can understand Maven is a nuclear-bomb-to-kill-an-ant when you work alone with a single and simple project setup. But add several OSes, several projects (which depends on each other, which is common internally in software companies) and several different teams working on the entire infrastructure, and you will how Maven can help you out (mainly if you're the manager). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have found no explanation and assume the problem is that the GPE has been updated and the documentation is old.

What has worked for me is to follow this video which an Android client being build to use an endpoint:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4

The video shows that one must build the endpoint client libraries (from GPE).  That generates some source files in the endpoints-lib.  Those source files are then copied to the client app.

In my case I was building a Java client app.  I followed the instructions for build and Android client app, which are here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android

That shows how to call the service from an Android app.  Specifically, it shows how to use the source classes that were copied to the client app from the endpoints-lib.  I had to make a few small adjustments.  In the end it seems to work.